# positioning footer at the bottom of the page using css

Tags: html, css

Here is my codepan link to show footer at bottom

But dont know why it shows space between footer and bottom of the page.

[image]

FIDDLE: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jprP6/)

code:

```
 <div id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">     
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">What is thenWat?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">How does it work?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Feedback</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>                            
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

css contains bootstrap.css and other inline css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS, I bet it will work like charm

```
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
```

with this CSS, even you resize your window it will not make difference to it. This will always keep your footer at bottom.

Comment: Did you got what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer{
    height: 34px; /* Think about this height */
    /* ... */
}
```